# Django: how to set ForeignKey related_name in Abstract Model class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create on Abstract Model class for future inheriting like this:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='XXX_created_by',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Field 'created_at' is working fine, but how to generate related_name in 'created_by' for my child classes to prevent clashing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [*Be careful with `related_name` and `related_query_name`* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name) says, you can:

> To work around this problem, when you are using `related_name` or `related_query_name` in an abstract base class (only), part of the value should contain `'%(app_label)s'` and `'%(class)s'`.
>
> - `'%(class)s'` is replaced by the lowercased **name of the child class** that the field is used in.
> - `'%(app_label)s'` is replaced by the lowercased **name of the app** the child class is contained within. Each installed application name must be unique and the model class names within each app must also be unique, therefore the resulting name will end up being different.

You thus can work with:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    # …
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='%(class)s_created_by',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then the `related_name` will be `foo_created_by` if the name of the model that inherits is named *`foo`*.

Or if the same model name can occur in different apps:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    # …
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then the `related_name` will be `bar_foo_created_by` if the name of the model that inherits is named *`foo`* in an app named *`bar`*.